# How to send and parse JSON data through NRF24L01 sensor?

Tags: json, iot, sensors, arduino-uno, nrf51

TRANSMITTER.ino (COM8 port)

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>
#include<ArduinoJson.h>
RF24 radio(7, 8); // CE, CSN
const byte addresses[6] = {"00001"};
void setup() {
 radio.begin();
 radio.openWritingPipe(addresses);
 radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
 radio.stopListening();
}
void loop() {
DynamicJsonBuffer jBuffer;
JsonObject& root = jBuffer.createObject();
root["North"] = "true";
root["South"] = "false";
root["East"] = "true";
root["West"] = "true";
radio.write(&root, sizeof(root));
delay(1000);
}
```

RECEIVER.ino  (COM9 port)

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>
#include<ArduinoJson.h>
RF24 radio(7, 8); // CE, CSN
const byte addresses[6] = {"00001"};
void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
radio.begin();
radio.openReadingPipe(0, addresses);
radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
radio.startListening();
}
void loop() {
if ( radio.available()) {
  unsigned char data[1024];
  radio.read(&data, sizeof(data));
  StaticJsonBuffer<1024> jsonBuffer;
  JsonObject& toor = jsonBuffer.parseObject(data);
  String n = toor["North"];
  String s = toor["South"];
  String e = toor["East"];
  String w = toor["West"];
  Serial.println(n);
  Serial.println(s);
  Serial.println(e);
  Serial.println(w);
  delay(1000);
 }
}
```

I am trying to transmit a JSON data over NRF24L01, and printing it to the serial monitor, but i dont see any output in my serial monitor(COM9 serial monitor). what is the mistake am i doing here?

I am using arduino JSON 5.13.5 version